# Deploy ear file to weblogic 12.1.3 from IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 x64

Tags: intellij-idea, weblogic12g

I have a java EE 5 project. I'm building a project with maven. I use IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 x64.I use weblogic 12.1.3. In the Department of deployment( edit configuration -> Deployment ) specify the ear file. Why doesn't IDEA put ear file in localhost:port/console -> deployments when running ?

Comment: Did you check the logs in the Run console? Was the ear deployed? Can you access it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Runtime Server is added correctly in IntelliJ. Once Added Correctly,You should see the **Application servers Tab**, where you could Add/Remove Applications effectively.

The Status of the deployment can be seen as **Module with a tick Mark** in Application Servers Tab.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, the ear file did not deploy due to the fact that I did not enter the domain name and password in the configuration

Comment: Thanks.I forgot to specify password in configuration